# Does “Children under 8 years old” include “8 years old?”

Tags: word-usage, numbers

Is the sentence "children under 8 years old" means 0-8 or 0-7? as I understand, less than 8 does not include 8. How about "under"? I just think about "under" as similar as "less" so I just think it does not include 8. But an activity marked as "children under 8 years old cannot participate in this..." does not sell a ticket for 8. So I wonder about it.

Comment: If I said *Pick any single-digit number **under** 8,* would you seriously consider choosing **8**? Go check a dictionary.

Comment: Related question https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/136949/9161

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Given that (a) the OP has already explained in an [earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159282) that their native language uses **different** words for 'greater than or equal to' and 'greater than'; (b) the OP has already postulated a hunch that the expression "under 8" would **not** include 8-year-olds, and (c) a dictionary may list upwards of [almost 20 definitions](https://www.wordnik.com/words/under) for the preposition _under_, I think this question seems legit, while your comment seems a bit condescending and insensitive toward our target audience.

Comment: The usual phrase used in North America is "children aged eight and under." The "and" makes it explicit that eight-year-olds are included.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers. Anyway, I am still a learner, maybe till end of my life, and I just want to make sure my understating. I am happy with every single sentences in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under means *less than* so, technically, an 8-year-old should not be participating in an "Under 8" activity.

If you were running such an activity, and wanted 8-year-olds to be included, you could either say, "Under 9", or "**Through** age 8". ("Up to age 8" is another valid way to say it.)

Comment: In addition to J.R.'s response; the school sports teams I am familiar with would set a certain date on which all team members had to be below a certain age - although they were permitted to continue playing for the team even if they reached that age before the end of the season.

Answer (score 0):

It technically would exclude eight-year-olds, but it's often used to include eight-year-olds. To avoid ambiguity, you should use a different term, such as "eight and under".

Answer (score -1):

8

7("*Under 8*" stars here by *including* "*7*" and all the numbers *below*)

6

5

..

.